# Saving between tabs

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, rxjs, tabs, observable

I am using a parent component with a simple [Tabstrip](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/tabstrip/) which has a bunch of tabs. Each tab is a child component. I would like to hold an object (called Student) with a bunch of attributes and maybe a list or two with other objects. On load I want to call an API to populate the student object and then I want to add the attributes to it from the various tabs.

```
<kendo-tabstrip>
   <kendo-tabstrip-tab title="Details" [selected]="true">
      <ng-template kendoTabContent>
         <createOrEditDetails #createOrEditDetails [(student)]="student"></createOrEditDetails>
      </ng-template>
   </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
   <kendo-tabstrip-tab title="ExtraInfo">
      <ng-template kendoTabContent>
         <createOrEditExtraInfo #createOrEditExtraInfo [(student)]="student"></createOrEditExtraInfo>
      </ng-template>
   </kendo-tabstrip-tab>                    
</kendo-tabstrip>
```

Would observables be a good start? On the parent ngOnInit I populate the global object student. It would then show the student "details" tab - If I change any items in the details tab I need to update the object...?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> If I change any items in the details tab I need to update the
>   object...?

Observables would be recommended here, you bind entire TabStrip to observable object and use that object in fields, once you change it in html input, for example, it will be changed in observable object, that's why its called MVVM (MODEL-VIEW VIEW-MODEL), it will be updated automatically and preserved through tabs.